# Segmentation fault when assigning values to pointers in function

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior

Long time listener, first time caller.

I do apologize if this problem has already been addressed (I imagine that is has been covered extensively), but I've searched through many questions about *pointers* and other seemingly related topics, but I still am unable to solve my problem.

I'm currently writing a *string* library for class project, and when I am getting a segmentation fault error when I try this:

```
#include "str2107.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void lstrip(char *s) {

        char *p, *q;
        p = q = s;

        while (*p == ' ' && *p != '\0') {
             *p++;
        }

        while (*p != '\0') {
            *q = *p;   //this is where the actual segmentation fault occurs.
            p++;
            q++;
        }

        *q = '\0';
}
```

My main program looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "str2107.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char *z1 = "      weeee";
    printf("lstrip function\n");
    printf("%s\n",z1);
    lstrip(z1);
    printf("%s\n",z1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: I hope you see the futility of the second half of this expression in a while-condition: `(*p == ' ' && *p != '\0')`. Under exactly what possible conditions will the first part be true and the second part be *false* ??? Shorter version: `(*p == ' ')`

Comment: +1 for providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ditto what he said --------^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`z1` is pointing to a *string literal* and modifying a string literal is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Alternatively you can use the following declaration of `z1` which will be modifiable:

```
char z1[] = "      weeee";
```

If we look at the C99 draft standard section `6.4.5` *String literals* paragraph *6* says(*emphasis mine*):

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the
>   appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

A few other points as WhozCraig points out this line:

```
while (*p == ' ' && *p != '\0') {
```

could be more succinctly written as:

```
while (*p == ' ' ) {
```

also you are using *indirection* here:

```
*p++;
```

but you don't actually use the resulting value, so you can change it to:

```
p++;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `char *z1 = "      weeee";` then `z1` is a *pointer* that points to a memory that is in the *code part*, so you can't change it.

If you change it `char z1[] = "      weeee";` then `z1` is an *array of chars* that are on the *stack* and you can change it.

If you had wrote `char const *z1 = "...";` then it would be a *compilation error*, which is better and preferable over segmentation fault.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It definitely cleared some things up!

Answer (score 0):

```
char *z1 = "      weeee";
```

should be

```
const char *z1 = "      weeee";
```

because string literals are constant. Try something like:

```
const char *z1 = "      weeee";
char *z2 = strdup(z1);
lstrip(z2);
```

To call `lstrip` on a mutable string while still keeping `z2` a `char*` (if it being a `char[]` isn't what you want).

Comment: Note that while attempting to modify a string literal invokes undefined behavior, string literals do not have `const` type in C.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson True. Perhaps I wasn't clear that the change should be made to prevent accidentally causing undefined behavior rather than for type agreement.

Comment: Perhaps. An alternative solution would be to write `char z1[] = "      weeee";`, creating `z1` as an array rather than a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As a lot of other people have already pointed out to you, when you write:

`char *whatever = "some value";`

This is much different than:

```
char *whatever = malloc(length("some value") + 1);
strcpy(whatever, "some value");
```

The difference being that something which is a literal (i.e. a string defined at compilation time) can be a constant, though I don't know if it is *always* or *required* to be constant.  Since a constant should not be modified, and you're placing a '\0' character into the string, this is causing a segmentation fault.

There may be a lot of reasons for this, but the easy one I know of is that the program can optimize if it knows that every use of the same string is safe to reuse.

As an example:

```
char *whatever1 = malloc(length("some value") + 1);
strcpy(whatever1, "some value");
char *whatever2 = malloc(length("some value") + 1);
strcpy(whatever2, "some value");
if(whatever1 == whatever2) {
  printf("This should never happen!\n");
}

if("some value" == "some value") {
  printf("A good compiler should always do this!\n");
}
```

Comment: String literals are not constant in C. That is, they do not have `const` type. What the standard says about it is simply that if your program attempts to modify one, the behavior is undefined. Most current C compilers will place string literals in a read-only section, but they are not required to, and it used to be that by default they didn't.